# How can I use an image or icon resource from global resource file in an asp:Image control to set the ImageUrl attribute?

Tags: asp.net, localization

How can I use an image or icon resource from global resource file in an asp:Image control to set the ImageUrl attribute?

Answer (score 1):

In code:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
myImage.ImageUrl= cs.GetWebResourceUrl(type, "resource name");
```

In the markup:

```
<asp:Image 
     ImageUrl="<%= Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(MyClass), 
     "resource name") %>" 
 />
```

See the documentation for [ClientScriptManager.GetWebResourceUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getwebresourceurl.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I used the code in the markup and I got this error 
Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Comment: Use the "In code" example instead. Put it in the Page_Load event.